# Factoring RSA-129 with a personal computer today

Tags: rsa, factoring

I have read the history of the RSA-129 challenge, and now I would like to know if it would be possible to factor RSA-129 with a single "average" personal computer, today. Has someone tried to do this particular factoring?

Answer (score 4):

From what I can gather it took about 2.5 months to factor a 512 bit RSA key on a personal computer from 2009 with a dual-core athlon64.

https://www.cemetech.net/projects/uti/viewtopic.php?t=8888

A typical desktop of today has about twice as many cores and twice the clockspeed. So that would cut it down to about two and a half weeks.

Furthermore modern processors have better IPC and your key is less than 512 bits.

So clearly doable but probablly not instant.

Comment: Just to be precise, the RSA-129 challenge was 426 bits.

Comment: The [CADO-NFS website](http://cado-nfs.gforge.inria.fr/) specifies 107 CPU hours for factoring RSA-130, so with a handful of cores this is clearly doable in less than a day.

Comment: I have tried CADO-NFS, but at the start of the sieving phase, after one day of computation, it crashes. I have tried with the latest release, and also with the stable version.